# Exclude everything after the second occurrence of a certain string

Tags: r, regex

I have the following string

```
string <- c('a - b - c - d',
            'z - c - b',
            'y',
            'u - z')
```

I would like to subset it such that everything after the second occurrence of ' - ' is thrown away.

The result would be this:

```
> string
[1]  "a - b" "z - c" "y"     "u - z"
```

I used `substr(x = string, 1, regexpr(string, pattern = '[^ - ]*$') - 4)`, but it excludes the last occurrence of ' - ', which is not what I want .

Comment: Have you already tried anything yet?

Comment: I have tried excluding everything after this match '[^ - ]*$', but it excludes the last occurrence of ' - ', which is not what I want

Comment: You mean you used that in a `sub`?

Comment: yes, `substr(x = string, 1, regexpr(string, pattern = '[^ - ]*$') - 4)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that you cannot use a *negated character class* to negate a *sequence* of characters. `[^ - ]*$` matches any 0+ chars other than a space (yes, it matches `-`, too, because the `-` created a range between  a space and a space) followed by the end of the string marker (`$`).

You may use a `sub` function with the following regex:

```
^(.*? - .*?) - .*
```

to replace with `\1`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TTWCWp/1).

R code:

```
> string <- c('a - b - c - d', 'z - c - b', 'y', 'u - z')
> sub("^(.*? - .*?) - .*", "\\1", string)
[1] "a - b" "z - c" "y"     "u - z"
```

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a string
- `(.*? - .*?)` - Group 1 (referred to with the `\1` backreference in the replacement pattern) capturing any 0+ chars *lazily* up to the first space, hyphen, space and then again any 0+ chars up to the next leftmost occurrence of space, hyphen, space
- `-`  - a space, hyphen and a space
- `.*` - any zero or more chars up to the end of the string.

Comment: works perfectly, just waiting to accept the answer. btw, can you recommend good resources to learn regex within the R framework?

Comment: It is a difficult question. You need to know that there is little info about the TRE (base R default regex flavor), there is a lot about PCRE (those cases when you use `perl=TRUE`) and some good amount of info devoted to the ICU regex flavor used by the *stringr* / *stringi* methods. Here is some [basic information about regexes in R](http://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html).

Answer (score 0):

try this `(\w(?:\s+-\s+\w)?).*`. For the explanation of the regex look this https://regex101.com/r/BbfsNQ/2.

That regex will retrieve the first tuple if exists or just the first caracter if there's not a tuple. So, the data is get into a "[capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)". Then to display the captured groups, it depends on the used language but in pure regex that will be `\1` to get the first group (`\2` to get second etc...). Look at the part "Substitution" on the regex101 if you wan't a graphic example.